# Azure ACS Kubernetes Windows Containers delayed access to internet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-acs, windows-server-container

I used the Azure portal to create an Azure ACS for windows containers yesterday 4/19/17. I find that whenever I deploy to it the container can't reach the internet for 2-3 minutes. I logged in to one of the nodes and manual created a container from the same image and it instantly can access the internet.

One difference I see is that the kubernetes owned containers contain an additional transparentNet where the plain docker container only has a nat network.

This is the test code I'm running

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectedStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        var disconnectedStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.DownloadString("http://google.com");
                    connectedStopWatch.Start();
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Connected for {connectedStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                connectedStopWatch.Stop();
                disconnectedStopWatch.Start();
                Console.WriteLine($"Disconnected for {disconnectedStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
COPY ConnectionTest.exe /
ENTRYPOINT ConnectionTest.exe
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the delay in accessing the internet from the container?

Comment: Azure takes a while to setup and propagate the required artifacts, which you just don't use when you just launch the container with Docker.

Comment: any idea what those artifacts would be or if there is a way to see what I'm waiting for? The cluster itself has been up and running for over a day.

Comment: During startup type kubectl describe to see what resources it is allocating. There are also delays displayed there.

Comment: so I did that, and I can post the results but the gist is that nothing changes except for first seen/last seen times between initial deploy and when calls to google start succeeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/issues/519.  We are testing a fix for this issue here, but will soon integrate into acs-engine: https://github.com/JiangtianLi/acs-engine/commits/jiangtli-winnat.

Comment: This bug seems to still exist. I have a brand new ACS Windows cluster and am seeing delays in outbound connectivity from my container apps. I also see periodic drops in connectivity, with either timeouts or "System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved". How should this sort of bug be reported?